# How to convert html inside TextField?

Tags: react-native

For displaying data, i will used "react-native-render-html",
But for editing records In my React Native app, I am pulling in JSON data that has raw HTML elements like thishello. 
so Is there any way to convert html text inside textfield?
Screenshot:
https://prnt.sc/n7ejbw

Comment: Can you try with this, var StrippedString = OriginalString.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");

Comment: Yeah,its work. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use [React-native-htmlView](https://github.com/jsdf/react-native-htmlview)
the usage of this plugin is pretty straight forward, even I have implemented this the same way as it is in example below

> this example is from the documentation

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet} from 'react-native';
import HTMLView from 'react-native-htmlview';

class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const htmlContent = `<p><a href="http://jsdf.co">&hearts; nice job!</a></p>`;

    return (
      <HTMLView
        value={htmlContent}
        stylesheet={styles}
      />
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  a: {
    fontWeight: '300',
    color: '#FF3366', // make links coloured pink
  },
});
```

Comment: I want to convert html inside TextField.
See the screenshot:
https://prnt.sc/n7ejbw

Comment: Yes , i got that , if u use HTMLView instead of textfield , u will get your code working .

Comment: Can I change text content ,if i put the HTML view.

Comment: Please help the community with the code . Attach that with the question

Comment: resolve my issue.
using these OriginalString.replace(/(<([^>]+)>)/ig,"");